# Need suggestion of creating instance of Collection

Tags: java, collections

So I found that `Collection` as an `Interface` has many sub-interfaces, and sub-Classes. One thing that is commonly seen is to use the interface instead of using the actual class, which allows flexibility:

```
List<Interger> L1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

But this also limits the use of some special methods in the actual `Class`, (in the case of `ArrayList`, not so many special methods). But this can be solved by using casting.

```
List<Integer> L2 = ((ArrayList<Integer>) L1).clone();
```

However, it is interesting that `LinkedList` is implementing `Collection`, `List`, `Queue`, `Deque`.

So what is the best scenario of using `LinkedList` in common?

```
List<> L1 = new LinkedList<>();
Queue<> Q1 = new LinkedList<>();
Deque<> D1 = new LinkedList<>();
```

1. If I use `List`, well then it seems unnecessary because I can make
   `List` from `ArrayList`.
2. Should I always choose the `Interface` that is just 1 level above the `Class`, in this case, `Deque` over `Queue`?

I guess it is just confusing because `Queue` and `Deque` does not implement `List`, but `LinkedList` does. And I don't see why should it be?

Thanks,

Comment: There is no "best" thing to use here. What kind of functionality do you need to use? Do you need those functionalities defined in `List` or `Queue` or `Deque`?

Comment: Because you can have implementations of `Queue` and `Deque` that are not Lists -- e.g., `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: You should choose a declared type that serves *all* your requirements for the object.  Typically, the most general type that does.  If you have to downcast then you've chosen wrongly (and any flexibility you thought you were gaining from the more general type is in that case illusory).

Comment: @JohnBollinger  Thanks! Always avoid downcasting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) components should depends on abstractions. So, first you need to choose the abstration which best meets your needs (e.g. interface or abstract class). And after that choose concrete implementation.

There is no the best solution for all cases.

Comment: But would you say that normally people will choose `ArrayList` above `LinkedList` to make a `List`?

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755 see here for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist-in-java

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks, very helpful!